# What lesson did he learn?

Tags: cipher, poetry

Kevin is a vegan. But not the good kind of vegan. The kind that insists everyone in his neighborhood needs to stop cooking meat at dinner time so he can run outside. Kevin pushed everyone around him so hard, even his vegan friends found it annoying. Now he feels alone. While eating his 2nd kale salad of the day, Kevin wrote a poem. He hid the lesson he learned within it. What's the lesson he wants to share with PSE?

He
alone
societally

will
evoke
alienism.

And
randomly,
seemingly,
reproduce.

Those
placebos
likened to
sensitivity.

Even
scolders
invite
bravoes
silently.

Hint 1:

> The line breaks are intentional, as are "."

Hint 2:

> This one may be early, so keeping it simple: keep the tags in mind

Hint 3:

> Up to one letter of the solution can be found per line

Hint 4:

> There was an original draft, containing the same hidden message/following the same pattern. 
> He
> alone
> societally,
> adversatively
> insociable.
> will
> randomly,
> seemingly,
> reproduce.
> [...] *No changes to the rest*

Hint 5:

> After a few days, Kevin was able to make amends with his friends. He wrote another little poem, using the same cipher, just to give everyone at PSE a *fifth hint*.
> Look
> ahead
> resited,
> instance
> rectified.
> Forgive
> gaffs
> like a flash,
> persevere
> blithely.

Hint 6:

> The poem is written by the cipher. As in, you don't start with a known work or other poem but start with your message to encode, and build around that. (It's not an efficient cipher in that sense). It may be possible to accomplish with known works, but highly unlikely.

Hint 7:

> A line following a blank line must contain 0 letters of the solution, and are the only lines(other than blank) that don't contribute to the solution.

Comment: I doubt if the sixth hint adds a significant benefit for the solvers as I believe most of us can infer the sixth hint from the fifth hint.

Comment: Good to know, I'm not sure how to describe it without giving it away

Comment: Hopefully combined with 7 and 3, 6 is more helpful? 7 is necessary, not arbitrary, based on another rule(really the only rule) of the cipher.

Comment: I'd actually guessed something that implies hint 7, though I haven't yet been able to make it work.

Comment: You can't be too far off then, best of luck

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have the answer, and I can see there is a pattern on how to get to it, I'm just not sure what the pattern is _exactly_...

Comment: Don't forget to award the bounty :-) It expires in a few hours.

Comment: Thanks! The email from that is what saved it. Thought it was awarded when I accepted the answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update - Thanks to @hagfy, the pattern has emereged.**

The final message is:

> LIVE AND LET LIVE

Which fits the story quite nicely.

The message can be extracted from the cipher poem as below:

> The line of each section has a letter of the answer at a particular index.  The full-stops indicate word breaks.
>
>  How to know which index to chose?
>
>  Originally I thought that the first line after a line break somehow contained some cipher metadata which identified the indexes to choose. However, this was misguided.
>
>  With some guiding light from @hagfy, the way to select the index is to take the number of syllables from the previous line and multiple them by two, and use the result as the index.
>  
>
>  `He                        - 1 syllable, next index = 2
>  alone         L - index 2 - 2 syllables, next index = 4
>  societally    I - index 4 - 5 syllables, next index = 10
>  
>  will                      - 1 syllable, next index = 2
>  evoke         V - index 2 - 2 syllables, next index = 4
>  alienism.     E - index 4 - 5 syllables, next index = 10
>  
>  And                       - 1 syllable, next index = 2
>  randomly,     A - index 2 - 3 syllables, next index = 6
>  seemingly,    N - index 6 - 3 syllables, next index = 6
>  reproduce.    D - index 6 - 3 syllables, next index = 6
>  
>  Those                     - 1 syllable, next index = 2
>  placebos      L - index 2 - 3 syllables, next index = 6
>  likened to    E - index 6 - 3 syllables, next index = 6
>  sensitivity.  T - index 6 - 5 syllables, next index = 10 
>  
>  Even                      - 2 syllables, next index = 4
>  scolders      L - index 4 - 2 syllables, next index = 4
>  invite        I - index 4 - 2 syllables, next index = 4
>  bravoes       V - index 4 - 2 syllables, next index = 4
>  silently.     E - index 4 - 2 syllables, next index = 4`
>
>   Because blank lines obviously have no syllables, any lines following a blank cannot contribute a letter to the solution, as index of zero is empty.

Regarding a couple of the hints:

Hint 4

> Spells the same thing, but without splitting "LIVE" across sections:
>  
>  `He
>  alone           L - index 2
>  societally,     I - index 4
>  adversatively   V - index 10
>  insociable.     E - index 10
>  
>  will
>  randomly,       A - index 2
>  seemingly,      N - index 6
>  reproduce.      D - index 6`

Hint 5:

> Literally spells out HINT FIVE
>  
>  `Look
>  ahead           H - index 2
>  resited,        I - index 4
>  instance        N - index 6
>  rectified.      T - index 4
>  
>  Forgive
>  gaffs           F - index 4
>  like a flash,   I - index 2
>  persevere       V - index 6
>  blithely.       E - index 6`

Comment: You've got the answers correct, will confirm that. +1 - but waiting for the why. Why *must* a line after a blank line have *0* characters of the solution?

Comment: I notice that rot13(vs lbh gnxr gur flyynoyr pbhag bs rnpu yvar ['frrzvatyl' = guerr] naq qbhoyr vg [fvk], gung frrzf gb zngpu gur vaqrk bs rnpu sbyybjvat yvar [ercebQhpr])

Comment: Thanks @hagfy - very well spotted! That works perfectly. I've updated the answer with this detail now.